# Spring 6 AOT for native image without Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, graalvm-native-image

any hints/examples how to include Sprint AOT into build without spring boot 3.0 or buildpacks? Or maybe with including spring boot but keeping old MVC code and xml bean definitions side by side with spring boot?

I'm using maven-shade-plugin + maven-native-plugin now and everything works except I'm missing AOT part.

Thanks.

Comment: What makes you think that when you use Spring Boot you have to throw out your MVC code and xml bean definitions? You can import the XML with `@ImportResource` into your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class. And if your MVC code works now it will so with Spring Boot. So instead of trying to shoehorn a AOT solution in there (as Spring only provides the infrastructure not the implementation as Spring Boot does) I would investigate to move to Spring Boot to bootstrap your application (and only bootstrap nothing more, nothing less).

Comment: @M.Deinum I was a little bit sceptical about possibility to easily merging spring mvc and spring boot. It turned out that it's not that hard. Finally managed to get it work with boot (as you suggested) and https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/native-image.html. Thanks.